# Mix blend not working in Astro with TailwindCSS

Tags: css, tailwind-css, astrojs, mix-blend-mode

I'm trying to build a navigation bar where the links are of color white (in the hero section i have an image) so when i scroll down i have a section of color white where i would like to add the mix-blend-mode: difference; property to achive what i want. I'm using Tailwind and Astro

I have tried without using tailwind, creating new pens, and a lot of things and i cant get it working, even following a simple tutorial. I readed the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode) for the mix blend but still cant get it working.

This is where i would like to add the mix blend:

```html
<header class="fixed left-0 top-0 z-[999999] w-full">
    <nav class=" z-[999] absolute flex items-center w-full justify-between p-6">
        Logo...
        <button class="opacity-100 text-montreal bg-white text-xl tracking-normal text-black rounded-md cursor-pointer px-4 py-2" id="logo-btn">⁜</button>
        Links...
        <ul class="text-montreal text-2xl [&_li]:cursor-pointer text-white flex items-center gap-5 [&_li]:leading-10">
            <li class="p relative flex flex-col">
                <div class="flex items-center justify-center gap-2">
                    Sell
                    some svg...
                </div>
                <div class="inner-line bg-white w-full h-[2px] absolute -bottom-2 opacity-0" />
            </li>
            <li class="p relative">
                Rent
                <div class="inner-line bg-white w-full h-[2px] absolute -bottom-2 opacity-0" />
            </li>
            <li class="p relative">
                Blog
                <div class="inner-line bg-white w-full h-[2px] absolute -bottom-2 opacity-0" />
            </li>
            <li class="p relative">
                Taxes
                <div class="inner-line bg-white w-full h-[2px] absolute -bottom-2 opacity-0" />
            </li>
        </ul>
        CTA...
        <button class="chronicle-button bg-white backdrop-blur-[1px] bg-opacity-15 outline-none border-none rounded-full p-4 flex items-center justify-center px-7 text-white text-montreal">
            <span>
                <em>Contact</em>
            </span>
            <span>
                <em>Contact</em>
            </span>
        </button>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Practicly in all of my elements, meaning that it could go into the logo, links, and the CTA button.

I'm adding the navbar in this section:

```html
<body class=" overflow-x-hidden bg-white w-full">
    <Navbar />
    <div class="h-screen bg-white">
        <div class="left-1/2 top-1/2 -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 h-full overflow-hidden relative">
            <img /> Image 1...
            <img /> Image 2...
            <img /> Image 3...
        </div>
    </div>
    <section class="bg-white h-full">Content...</section>
</body>
```

Anything helpful will be welcome. Thanks

Comment: You mean like [this](https://play.tailwindcss.com/YS7GEY9QIS)? You would just need to add `mix-blend-difference` to the header's class list.

Comment: @JHeth yeah that's how I wanted to do it, I totally passed it, thanks a lot mate, you really helped me!